# Bad performance 32bits apps vs Azure SQL elasticpool

Tags: azure, performance, vb6, vb6-migration, azure-elasticpool

**Hello to the Best Community ever!**

I'm facing some performance problems with Azure SQL elastic pool. Thank you for reading!

The picture... i'm migrating to Azure our systems. Part of our core business is written in **32 bits applications**. I believed that the Azure Sql elastic pool would be a good choice, but the performance **run down x3**. I think that the problem is how these 32bits apps negotiate the connection with the database. Also tried several MS's ODBCs and third party drivers. [Devart´s one](https://www.devart.com/odbc/), for example. Without success. XS

I'm writing this hoping someone had the same issue and **solved it**. MS don't give us much support and refactoring the code is not an option right now.

The walkthrought is to install several virtual machines with sql servers and re-migrate from elastic pool. But that would take more time including replannification.

I hope this is all about configuration and/or finding the correct driver...
I hope this thread finds you.

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to add some "beef" to your question. As a start, add your ADO connection string _(assuming you're using ADO)_. And a code example interacting with the database they you now is slower than before would also help to spot potential issues.